# R Data table - add vector of values as a column

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a new column inside my data table, this column being a vector of values; but I am getting the following error:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b"),c(2,3)),y=1:5)
> 
> DT
   x y
1: a 1
2: a 2
3: b 3
4: b 4
5: b 5
> DT[, my_vec := rep(0,y)]
Error in rep(0, y) : invalid 'times' argument
```

My expected result is:

```
> DT
   x y my_vec
1: a 1 0
2: a 2 0 0
3: b 3 0 0 0
4: b 4 0 0 0 0
5: b 5 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is a little cumbersome, but you can do this:

```
DT[, my_vec := list(list(rep(0, y))), by = y]
DT
#   x y    my_vec
#1: a 1         0
#2: a 2       0,0
#3: b 3     0,0,0
#4: b 4   0,0,0,0
#5: b 5 0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear whether you need a `list` as `my_vec` or a `vector`.  If it is the latter, we group by sequence of rows, replicate the 0 with 'y' and `paste` the elements together within each group.

```
DT[, my_vec := paste(rep(0, y), collapse=' ') , 1:nrow(DT)]
DT
#   x y    my_vec
#1: a 1         0
#2: a 2       0 0
#3: b 3     0 0 0
#4: b 4   0 0 0 0
#5: b 5 0 0 0 0 0
```